# SOLR DataImport Error "Unable to Execute Query"

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, solr

I have a website running on an Amazon EC2 Instance, and I'm trying to get Solr to interface and work with the database I'm using. I'm able to use the admin interface and have gotten the example xml files indexed, but whenever I try to import one of my database tables, I get the error

```
SEVERE: Exception while processing: gamelydb document : SolrInputDocument[{}]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException:
 Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM league Processing Document # 1
```

Here's my data-config.xml file. I also added the dataimporthandler to the solrconfig.xml file.

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://www.mysite.com/mydb"
              user="root"
              password="mypassword"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="mydb"
            query="SELECT * FROM league">
       <field column="id" name="id" />
       <field column="leaguename" name="leaguename" />
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Any idea why this is happening? And just let me know if I need to clarify anything.

So I changed the url a bit and removed the 'http://' and that error seemed to go away. However none of the information seems to be searchable through the admin. There are now a few files in the data directory (_1.fnm, _1.frq,...). Here is what solr prints to the log.

```
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:45 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={} status=0 QTime=4
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:48 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={command=full-import} status=0 QTime=4
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:48 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
INFO: Starting Full Import
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:48 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
INFO: Read dataimport.properties
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:48 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 deleteAll
INFO: [] REMOVING ALL DOCUMENTS FROM INDEX
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:48 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy onInit
INFO: SolrDeletionPolicy.onInit: commits:num=1
        commit{dir=/home/ec2-user/public_html/solr/example/solr/data/index,segFN=segments_2,version=1310405039852,generation=2,filenames=[_0.tis, _0.nrm, _0.fnm, _0.tii, _0.frq, segments_2, _0.fdx, _0.fdt]
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:48 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy updateCommits
INFO: newest commit = 1310405039852
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:48 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call
INFO: Creating a connection for entity gamelydb with URL: jdbc:mysql://www.gamely.us/gamelydb
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call
INFO: Time taken for getConnection(): 667
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder finish
INFO: Import completed successfully
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit
INFO: start commit(optimize=true,waitFlush=false,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false)
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy onCommit
INFO: SolrDeletionPolicy.onCommit: commits:num=2
        commit{dir=/home/ec2-user/public_html/solr/example/solr/data/index,segFN=segments_2,version=1310405039852,generation=2,filenames=[_0.tis, _0.nrm, _0.fnm, _0.tii, _0.frq, segments_2, _0.fdx, _0.fdt]
        commit{dir=/home/ec2-user/public_html/solr/example/solr/data/index,segFN=segments_3,version=1310405039855,generation=3,filenames=[_1.fdx, _1.tis, _1.frq, _1.fdt, _1.tii, _1.fnm, _1.nrm, segments_3]
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy updateCommits
INFO: newest commit = 1310405039855
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher <init>
INFO: Opening Searcher@1c4795e main
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming Searcher@1c4795e main from Searcher@1d38b87 main
        fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@1c4795e main
        fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming Searcher@1c4795e main from Searcher@1d38b87 main
        filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@1c4795e main
        filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming Searcher@1c4795e main from Searcher@1d38b87 main
        queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=1,evictions=0,size=1,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@1c4795e main
        queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming Searcher@1c4795e main from Searcher@1d38b87 main
        documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@1c4795e main
        documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
INFO: QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@1c4795e main
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
INFO: QuerySenderListener done.
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit
INFO: end_commit_flush
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore registerSearcher
INFO: [] Registered new searcher Searcher@1c4795e main
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher close
INFO: Closing Searcher@1d38b87 main
        fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
        filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
        queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=1,evictions=0,size=1,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
        documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
INFO: Read dataimport.properties
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter persist
INFO: Wrote last indexed time to /home/ec2-user/public_html/solr/example/solr/./conf/dataimport.properties
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {deleteByQuery=*:*,add=[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],optimize=} 0 4
Jul 13, 2011 1:19:49 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder execute
INFO: Time taken = 0:0:1.66
```

EDIT: If you find something on here that's downvotable, please just let me know so I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `url` parameter.
If the MySQL database is on the same machine, then use `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"`
If its on www.mysite.com, then use `url="jdbc:mysql://www.mysite.com/mydb"`

Also, your log files may have more details regarding the error - please go through the logs and post the appropriate entries here.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. My database is on the same machine.
In data-config.xml, I changed the line:

`url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"`

to

`url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb"`

and then things worked. Strange are the ways of Solr/Lucene!

Comment: Most probably, the reason for that isn't related to Solr or Lucene. It's related to Java using IPv6. Thus, 'localhost' gets resolved to "::1" instead of 127.0.0.1. which mysql can't recognize. To force Java to use IPv4 instead (on Linux), use: export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing oone of the following troubleshotting:

- Use `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:1433/mydb` in case the sqlDB was installed on the same machine.
- Check the Tomcat folder for errors (Catalina file).
- Enable the auditing on the database level and check the logs on it.