# solr data import handler working on localhost and not on server

Tags: mysql, solr, vps, dih

i have been trying to configure solr-DIH on server which has about 5 million documents and it is not working but it is working well on my localhost with 100000 documents.what can be the problem?

this is the log i am getting

```
Exception while processing: product_master document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT cs_product_id,title FROM product_master Processing Document # 1
16:10:56
SEVERE
DataImporter
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT cs_product_id,​title
```

my data-config goes here

```xml
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://www.mysite.com/mydb" user="myusername" password="mypwd" batchSize="-1"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="product_master" pk="cs_product_id" 
            query="SELECT cs_product_id,title FROM product_master" 
            deltaImportQuery=" SELECT cs_product_id,title FROM product_master WHERE cs_product_id = '${dataimporter.delta.cs_product_id}'" 
            deltaQuery=" SELECT cs_product_id FROM product_master WHERE update_timestamp > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
            <field column="cs_product_id" name="cs_product_id"/>
            <field column="title" name="title"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: please provide more info about it...what exception you are getting? Did you checked the log?

Comment: i checked the log @abhijit

Comment: Exception while processing: product_master document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT cs_product_id,title FROM product_master Processing Document # 1
16:10:56
SEVERE
DataImporter
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT cs_product_id,​title

Comment: check the connection String.Check the url you have mentioned...jdbc:mysql://HOST/DATABASE

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666692/solr-dataimport-error-unable-to-execute-query

Comment: Please share the data-config.xml...

Comment: i changed everything according to that particular question @abhijeet

Comment: did the changes worked for you? whats the exception now?

Comment: try by removing batchSize="-1" .

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference so I suggest you to do the following:

- set to DEBUG the log level of DIH components
- create a simple class with a simple main method that does something trivial with that database, using that exact connection URL, exact username and password

I think with one of the two tricks above you will get the point (which, as I guess, has nothing to do with Solr)