# Cannot index mysql using Apache Solr

Tags: mysql, solr

I am trying to index a mysql database (for now just the employees Sample DB before I move onto the production DB), but I just cannot get a grasp on this.

I just get full import failed, as you can see below:
[image]

I really don't know what to do since I followed the DIH example in the Solr Reference manual, and I changed the solrconfig.xml and the db-data-config.xml, and I cannot figure out why it doesnt work.

My database consists entirely of the stock MySQL Employees DB

I am running MySQL 5.7 on Linux Mint virtualbox on top of windows

I don't know what else to include to help out, please let me know what other info is needed.

Logs:

[image]

Comment: What are the logs saying ?

Comment: You probably want to use `name="item"` in the entity, then have `field` entries under it to map columns to Solr fields: `<field column="id" name="id" />`. Also, try losing the "LIMIT" statement and the ending semicolon in your query.

Comment: Please show us you db configuration settigs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOLR DataImport Error "Unable to Execute Query"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666692/solr-dataimport-error-unable-to-execute-query)